# Should i implement my key/value system in memory or in MS SQL or 3rd party?

Tags: database, nosql, schema, key-value

I think I've done enough research to know that i want to go with a NOsql key/value route.  I've read up as much as i can and have the following questions still:

- should i go with something like amazon simpledb, google big table or microsoft azure's solution?  (note i'm a .NET site)
- why not just simply create an in memory hashtable of keys/objects (assuming memory is abundant enough to story everything)?
- how about creating a table in my SQL server with two columns, one a key and one a value.  the key is the primary key and the value is a string of whatever i want.  i'll have to pull the string out and parse it into something meaningful though.
- shoudl i go with something like neo4j graph database?

it's unclear to me which path i should take.

Comment: I can't answer the question, only provide something to add to your research list: http://www.ravendb.net/ is a .NET NoSQL "document database". Hmm licensing isn't much fun though (to the extent that personally I won't now be bothering with the download).

Comment: I see you didn't mention [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). This might be an option to consider as well.

Comment: Please explain the context.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is if you really want a key value type system pick a noSQl database. Relational databases do not do a good job of handling key-value type queries and they are real performance killers in a relational database. IF you are going this route, use the right tool for it.

Comment: curious about simply using a ms sql table with two columns for the key/value - that seems pretty fast to me to do it this way.  it's simply a lookup table with an indexed primary key - how would that be a performance killer?